# Geth PoA Clique and Chain Forks

Tags: go-ethereum, poa, clique

In PoW, in the case of a chain fork, the client will continue on the chain with the most work on it.

In Geth PoA Clique, forks still can ocur, since Sealers are racing against each other in sealing blocks. If a fork is detected, how to the node decided on which chain to continue? On the deepest chain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, ethereum will reorg and choose the chain with more difficulty. in the PoA, if the signer is in-turn the difficulty is 2 and 1 when out-turn.